# Phonegap real time camera capture

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to build an app where my page background is the image from the camera (real time, update as I move)

Does somebody know a plugin or a way to capture the camera 'view' into canvas or background-image on a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible-Plugin: https://github.com/shaithana/cordova-plugin-wezka-nativecamera

You do not get around the problem to put a captured image on a canvas element on your own:

```
var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: window.innerWidth,
    targetHeight: window.innerHeight,
    correctOrientation: true
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageData) {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var image = new Image();
  image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  };

}, function (err) {
   console.log(err);
// An error occurred. Show a message to the user
}, options);
```

Style:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body, html { height:100%; }

#c {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Does the captured images will be saved on the phone?

Comment: No, for this to work you need to put the imageData to localStorage or Sqlite-Db. This plugin is pretty great for this job:  https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Comment: No problem, you are welcome. When you save a base64-Image(imageData) then be careful it blows your db up by using a great deal of memory